# Excel Cell = Cell

Tags: excel

I have set up 4 sheets within a workbook.

The first sheet has every Colum in it and the other three are segments of the first.

If I'm on sheet two I can add "=Sheet1!A2" and it will copy the value of that cell. However, is there a way that I can configure so that if I want to change a value on Sheet 2 Cell A2 I can do that on Sheet 2 and then it update Sheet1.

I don't know how to even attempt searching this on google, so I have turned to yourselves for help.

Thanks,

Comment: You want both Sheet1!A2 and Sheet2!A2 to always be the same?

Comment: Would love to see someone post an answer, I've only been able to do it with a Macro

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly that's called a `circular reference` and can't be done.

Comment: Can't be done with formulas, You will need to use vba in a Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: How would I do it via Macro/VBA

Comment: It might be easier to have a macro that does the formatting of the 3 sheets on the first sheet, eg make the main sheet "look" like sheet2. Then if you update it'll always be right, as you only have one place for the data.